Where can one find research proposals in mathematical disciplines such as theoretical CS and Operations research?
Does anyone know where I might find sample research proposals specifically related to these disciplines?
Are there repositories, university archives, or publications that make such documents accessible?

This is off-topic, it's what we call a "shopping" questions where we are asked to supply list of things.

There is generally no such resource. People treat proposals as confidential, at least the ones that were not funded, because they might still want to re-use the text and ideas for future proposals. As a consequence, they are not typically made public and there will be no institution or archive that collects them.
People are often a bit more lenient giving out proposals that were funded, but they too are not made public by researchers' institutions or funding agencies. That is, you will only be able to get access to such proposals if a researcher specifically gives it to you. For that, at the very least, you will have to explain why you want it.
